# Adding Schedule Engine Widget to Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, sanity

So I'm pretty new to Reactjs and gatsby and learn as I go. I have a client website that was built on react and gatsby and sanity. And I thought something simple to add turns out I'm at a stump.

my question is, how do I implement an onclick they provided?

```
<script data-api-key="the API Key provided by Schedule Engine" data-defer="true" id="se-widget-embed" src="https://embed.scheduleengine.net/schedule-engine-v3.js"></script>
```

is the script to add to the body or head and to Activate the CTA they also sent this

```
<button class="se-widget-button" type="button" onclick="ScheduleEngine.show()">Book Now!</button>
```

I tried adding it as onClick"ScheduleEngine.show()" to a button, but it's giving me an error.

Please go easy on me :)

Comment: That's not typically how you add a click event to a button in React. It should look something like `onClick=(() => { this.ScheduleEngine.show() })`. What error are you seeing?

Comment: @MatthewM. giving me  119:60  error  Parsing error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text.

> 119 |           <a href="#" className="se-widget-button" onClick=(() => { this.ScheduleEngine.show() })>Book Now!</a>
      |                                                            ^

Comment: Sorry, I typo'd the earlier one. Try: onClick={() => {this.ScheduleEngine.show()}}

Comment: @MatthewM. Sorry to bother you, but if ended giving me an error " TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ScheduleEngine') "

Comment: Try removing "this".

Comment: @MatthewM. So when I removed "this" gave me an error of 'ScheduleEngine' is not defined... Sorry if I have been bothering you too much